# How to get the top 1 row when we order by date, for users grouped in one team

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table

```html
Id SubmittedUserId DateSubmitted TeamId PrivateScore PublicScore
2180 647.0 2010-04-29 22:32:08 496 56.21390151977539 55.76919937133789
2181 619.0 2010-04-30 09:38:29 497 50.0 47.11539840698242
2182 619.0 2010-04-30 09:48:50 497 65.60690307617188 61.057701110839844
2184 663.0 2010-05-01 11:02:52 499 50.0 47.11539840698242
2185 673.0 2010-05-02 08:04:38 500 62.283199310302734 61.057701110839844
2186 673.0 2010-05-02 08:13:43 500 62.86130142211914 60.576900482177734
2187 673.0 2010-05-02 08:25:09 500 65.75140380859375 62.5
2188 435.0 2010-05-03 17:48:39 501 50.0 47.11539840698242
2191 435.0 2010-05-04 15:39:56 501 56.502899169921875 55.28850173950195
2192 647.0 2010-05-04 18:56:15 496 56.3583984375 57.21149826049805
2193 652.0 2010-05-04 21:29:39 502 56.791900634765625 56.25
2194 435.0 2010-05-04 22:13:17 501 55.635799407958984 55.76919937133789
2195 652.0 2010-05-04 22:54:07 502 56.64739990234375 53.84619903564453
2196 652.0 2010-05-04 23:46:06 502 55.78030014038086 52.40380096435547
2197 435.0 2010-05-05 00:32:56 501 48.84389877319336 45.192298889160156
2198 435.0 2010-05-05 01:19:13 501 56.069400787353516 55.28850173950195
```

and I want to write a query to get the following table:

```html
Id SubmittedUserId DateSubmitted TeamId PrivateScore PublicScore totalsubmissions     
2180 647         5/4/2010 18:56 496     56.35839844 57.21149826 2     
2182 619         4/30/2010 9:48 497     65.60690308 61.05770111 2     
2184 663      5/1/2010 11:02 499     50         47.11539841 1     
2187 673         5/2/2010 08:25 500     65.75140380 62.5     4     
2198 435         5/5/2010 1:19 501   56.06940079 55.28850174 5
```

I wrote the following query which is wrong. I do not know how to write it.

```
select COUNT(*), 
top 1 Id, SubmittedUserId, DateSubmitted, TeamId, PublicScore, PrivateScore
from [Kaggle].[dbo].[Submissions]
order by DateSubmitted desc 
Group by  TeamId
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle? Add the proper tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (partition by TeamId
                              order by DateSubmitted ) as rn,
           count(*) over (partition by TeamId) as total_submission
    from [Kaggle].[dbo].[Submissions]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Juan. I appreciate your help. It worked :) but How about totalsubmissions?

Comment: I am wondering after grouping by team and ordering based on date, if I want to get the public score of the team from the previous line how should I change this code? Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow me to create a new Question. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you been banned from asking new question? First time I hear something like that

Comment: You may want to check `LAG()` and `LEAD()`